# Application dropping connection to Salesforce, any way to retry on Exception?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I wrote an application that connects to Salesforce.com via the API and queries and updates the data.  Sometimes, a method, like the one below, will fail to connect and cause the whole application to stop running:

`Exception in getMoreResults(): 
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.`

What's the best way to retry the `qr = sfservice.queryMore(qr.Locator)` execution on failure?  Ideally, I'd like to try it three times before logging a failure and stopping execution of the program.  Below is some pseudo code, although I'm not sure how feasible it is.  Any help is much appreciated!

```
public QueryResult getMoreResults(QueryResult qr)
    {

        try
        {
            qr = sfservice.queryMore(qr.queryLocator);
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            bool success = false;
            //Todo retry this query until it is either successful or has failed three times
            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                //somehow set success boolean here

                if(success == false)
                {
                    qr = sfservice.queryMore(qr.queryLocator);
                    //log error and error attempt
                }
                else
                {
                    //exit this method and return to normal flow?
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //log the error
            AppSettings.log.Error(ex.Message.ToString());
        }

        return qr;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pseudocode:

```
For i as Integer = 1 To 3
    Try
         qr = sfservice.queryMore(qr.queryLocator)
         Exit For
    Catch ex as Exception
    End Try
Next i
```